# Hacer un gráfico con ggplot2 en facet_grid con los grupos de una prueba de Fisher

Tags: r

Tengo un grupo de datos (DF), que están en un diseño factorial para analizarlos.

```
FactorA <- c(90,180,0,180,90,90,0,0,180,0,180,180,90,90,180,90,0,0,180,180,90,90,0,180,90,0,0,90,180,0,180,90,90,0,0,180,0,180,180,90,90,180,90,0,0,180,180,90,90,0,180,90,0,0,90,180,0,180,90,90,0,0,180,0,180,180,90,90,180,90,0,0,180,180,90,90,0,180,90,0,0)
FactorB <- c(180,360,180,0,0,360,0,360,180,360,180,360,0,180,0,360,180,0,0,180,0,360,180,360,180,0,360,180,360,180,0,0,360,0,360,180,360,180,360,0,180,0,360,180,0,0,180,0,360,180,360,180,0,360,180,360,180,0,0,360,0,360,180,360,180,360,0,180,0,360,180,0,0,180,0,360,180,360,180,0,360)
Variable1 <- c(65,95,50,32,43,102,29,112,76,120,50,85,25,58,32,80,65,25,41,42,29,90,60,75,50,35,120,40,85,47,14,20,82,10,125,78,116,75,83,8,40,11,85,69,9,13,71,11,79,35,82,43,9,120,62,122,65,24,33,114,11,98,80,154,74,126,10,57,21,146,79,11,16,58,9,153,49,124,44,13,126)
Variable2 <- c(110,164,80,218,96,115,75,91,174,84,189,132,91,103,174,98,71,56,151,132,73,55,49,178,117,50,83,166,180,153,171,97,180,71,173,184,168,126,168,131,116,110,142,108,65,118,133,100,161,93,148,137,68,163,120,134,58,171,129,116,51,113,124,97,129,125,96,130,91,126,81,61,131,120,73,125,52,151,111,41,77)
Tiempo <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Tratamiento <- c("T05","T09","T02","T07","T04","T06","T01","T03","T08","T03","T08","T09","T04","T05","T07","T06","T02","T01","T07","T08","T04","T06","T02","T09","T05","T01","T03","T05","T09","T02","T07","T04","T06","T01","T03","T08","T03","T08","T09","T04","T05","T07","T06","T02","T01","T07","T08","T04","T06","T02","T09","T05","T01","T03","T05","T09","T02","T07","T04","T06","T01","T03","T08","T03","T08","T09","T04","T05","T07","T06","T02","T01","T07","T08","T04","T06","T02","T09","T05","T01","T03")
Bloque <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")

DF <- data.frame(FactorA, FactorB, Variable1, Variable2, Tiempo, Tratamiento, Bloque)
DF$FactorA1 <- as.factor(DF$FactorA)
```

El diseño es factorial con tres repeticiones en bloques (la columna bloque la pongo únicamente para el ANOVA, pero es la repetición), y esto se repitió tres veces en el tiempo. Necesito analizar los datos por separado cada vez que se realizó el experimento, por lo que divido la base de datos y hago los ANOVA y la prueba de Fisher en cada tiempo.

```
DF1 <- subset(DF, Tiempo == 1)
DF2 <- subset(DF, Tiempo == 2)
DF3 <- subset(DF, Tiempo == 3)

library(agricolae)

AovV1<-aov(Variable1 ~ Tratamiento + Bloque, data = DF1)
summary(AovV1)

FhV1 <- LSD.test(AovV1,"Tratamiento", group=TRUE,console=TRUE)
bar.group(FhV1$groups, ylim=c(0,140),density=10, col=4,border="black")

AovV2<-aov(Variable1 ~ Tratamiento + Bloque, data = DF2)
summary(AovV2)

FhV2 <- LSD.test(AovV2,"Tratamiento", group=TRUE,console=TRUE)
bar.group(FhV2$groups, ylim=c(0,140),density=10, col=4,border="black")

AovV3<-aov(Variable1 ~ Tratamiento + Bloque, data = DF3)
summary(AovV3)

FhV3 <- LSD.test(AovV3,"Tratamiento", group=TRUE,console=TRUE)
bar.group(FhV3$groups, ylim=c(0,170),density=10, col=4,border="black")
```

De esto obtengo, para el año 1, por ejemplo:

```
    Variable1 groups
T03 117.33333      a
T06  90.66667      b
T09  85.00000      b
T02  58.33333      c
T05  57.66667      c
T08  56.00000      c
T07  35.00000      d
T04  32.33333      d
T01  29.66667      d
```

La columna "Variable1" muestra la media de cada tratamiento y la columna "group" las diferencias estadísticas que muestra el test de Fisher. 
Me gustaría mostrar estos datos de forma gráfica, por lo que hago:

```
library (ggplot2)

ggplot(data = DF) +
  aes(x = FactorA1, weight = Variable) +
  geom_bar(data=DF,
           aes(x=FactorA1, y=Variable), 
           stat = "summary", 
           fill = "#0c4c8a", 
           fun.y = "mean") +
  facet_grid(Tiempo ~ FactorB)+
  labs(subtitle="Factor B",
       x="Factor A",  
       y="Variable", 
       caption="") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Y obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por un lado, estaría necesitando poner un titulo que diga "Tiempo" en el lado derecho del gráfico. 
Por otro lado, necesitaría poner los grupos de los analisis de Fisher (las letras a, b, c...) arriba de cada barra. Hay que tener en cuenta que cada grupo corresponde a un analisis diferente que se realizó para cada tiempo.
Además, de poderse, me gustaría tener otro gráfico igual pero con la "Variable1" y "Variable2" con barras dobles.
Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Agregar titulo derecho

Desde `ggplot()` y las funciones `facet_*` increíblemente no se puede (al menos hasta dónde conozco y a la fecha). Pero puedes apoyarte en los paquetes [`gridExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html) o [`grid`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid) que básicamente te permitirán organizar con cierto orden, múltiples gráficos. La idea podría ser, que tengas tu gráfico en la primer celda de una tabla de dos columnas y una fila, y en la segunda celda ajustar un `geom_text()` vertical para establecer el título que quieres. Sin embargo, si tus necesidades son más sencillas, también puedes darle un título a la derecha a la celda:

```
ggplot(data = DF) +
  aes(x = FactorA1, weight = Variable) +
  geom_bar(data=DF,
           aes(x=FactorA1, y=Variable), 
           stat = "summary", 
           fill = "#0c4c8a", 
           fun.y = "mean") +
  facet_grid(Tiempo ~ FactorB) +
  labs(subtitle="Factor B",
       x="Factor A",  
       y="Variable", 
       caption="") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) -> p

library("gridExtra")
grid.arrange(p, right="Tiempo")
```

En este ejemplo, defines una única celda, con la gráfica y le asignas un título a la derecha, rápido pero algo sucio.

#### Agregar los grupos a la gráfica

En primer lugar, entiendo que estas hablando de la variable `Bloque`. Algo que debería haber mencionado antes que nada, es, que cuando trabajos con múltiples dimensiones en un gráfico, es mucho más cómodo y fácil de leer, si elaboras los datos acorde a lo que necesitas y evitar trabajar con las funciones estadísticas incorporadas de `ggplot`. Por ejemplo, la gráfica anterior podríamos haberla creado directamente de un `data.frame` a la medida, con la media ya calculada:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(FactorB, Tiempo, FactorA1) %>% 
  summarize(Variable=mean(Variable)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=FactorA1, y=Variable)) +
    geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a") + 
    facet_grid(Tiempo ~ FactorB, scales = "fixed") +
    labs(subtitle="Factor B",
         x="Factor A",  
         y="Variable", 
         caption="") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) -> p

grid.arrange(p, right="Tiempo")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrás ver que:

- Usamos un poco de `dplyr` (del meta paquete `tidyverse`) para agrupar y calcular la media.
- La función *"pipe"* `%>%, por si no lo conocías, [aquí](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html) una buena introducción
- Con el nuevo `data.frame`, usamos directamente un `geom_col()` que es equivalente a  un `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`, útil cuando la estadística ya la tenemos calculada.

Y ahora, si queremos agregar `Bloque` a la gráfica, deberemos establecer una nueva dimensión estética al gráfico. Usaremos `group` para separar cada barra, y, además, en vez de usar un único color, usaremos la dimensión `fill` para diferenciar mejor todas ellas. Además incorporamos un `geom_text()` para agregar las etiquetas de cada `Bloque` sobre cada barra.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("gridExtra")

DF %>% 
  group_by(FactorB, Tiempo, FactorA1, Bloque) %>% 
  summarize(Variable=mean(Variable)) %>% 
  ungroup()  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=FactorA1, y=Variable, group=Bloque)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Bloque), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Bloque), position = position_dodge(0.9), , vjust= -0.3) +
  ylim(0, max(new_DF$Variable)+10) +
  facet_grid(Tiempo ~ FactorB) +
  labs(subtitle="Factor B",
       x="Factor A",  
       y="Variable", 
       caption="") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position="none") -> p

grid.arrange(p, right="Tiempo")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Si igual quieres mantener un único color para las barras, puedes usar `geom_col(position = "dodge", fill = "#0c4c8a", color="white")`

Comment: Patricio, 
lo del titulo a la derecha es así, muchas gracias.
Sobre el resto, lo que necesito es en primer lugar es un gráfico con las medias y los grupos del Fisher y luego un gráfico con las medias de una variable 2 en columnas apiladas.
Los bloques son la repetición de los tratamientos en distintos lugares y lo pongo por el análisis de varianza (aov).
Probablemente me haya explicado mal, ya edite la pregunta para ser más claro.
Muchas gracias!!